# String replace not working when called from cmd

Tags: powershell, cmd

I have the following PowerShell-Command which works perfectly fine when called from powershell directly:

```
Get-ChildItem -r -include 'AssemblyInfo.cs' `
| foreach-object { $a = $_.fullname; ( get-content $a ) `
| foreach-object { $_ -replace '((\[assembly:\sAssemblyVersion\(")(\d\.\d\.\d\.\d)("\)\]))', '$1[assembly:AssemblyInformationalVersion("$3-alpha")]' } ` 
| Out-File $_.fullname }
```

However, when called from cmd (our Buildservers-Process runs in cmd) it does not raise an error but it also does't replace the string as expected (it can be reproduced from any cmd-window):

```
PowerShell -Command "(Get-ChildItem -r -include  'AssemblyInfo.cs') | foreach-object { $a = $_.fullname; ( get-content $a ) | foreach-object { $_ -replace '((\[assembly:\sAssemblyVersion\(")(\d\.\d\.\d\.\d)("\)\]))', '$1[assembly:AssemblyInformationalVersion("$3-alpha")]' } | Out-File $_.fullname }"
```

I tried around with escaping quotation-marks and commands using `and`&` but it didn't help.

What am i missing out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have double quotes inside your command string:

```
... -replace '((\[assembly:\sAssemblyVersion\(")(\d\.\d\.\d\.\d)("\)\]))', ...
                                              ^                  ^
```

These must be escaped for CMD:

```
... -replace '((\[assembly:\sAssemblyVersion\(\")(\d\.\d\.\d\.\d)(\"\)\]))', ...
                                              ^^                  ^^
```